# How to read a line into variables, which is in 'var=value' format, in a bash script?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to read a line from output, which looks like this (it comes from slurm, for those who are familiar with it):

> cpu=00:00:00,energy=0,fs/disk=1389.75K,mem=556K,pages=0,vmem=203640K

After reading the line, there should be variables `cpu`, `energy`, a.s.o. with the respective value.

Initially I tried to `source` the output via piping:

```
line=$(tr ',/' ';_' <<< "cpu=00:00:00,energy=0,fs/disk=1389.75K,mem=556K,pages=0,vmem=203640K)"
source <<< $line
. <<< $line
```

But that doesn't work since `source` and `.` needs a file. So my working attempt now is:

```
file=$(mktemp)
{ sacct [...] | tr ',/' ';_' > $file && source $file && rm $file } || echo "Error"
```

My question would be: is there a better way to achieve the same result without creating a temporary file?

Comment: Use process substitution (which might still create a temporary file, but the shell will manage that for you). `source <(tr ... <<< ...)`. (Note that `<<<` creates a temporary file as well; you can use `echo "..." | tr ...` instead.)

Answer (score 2):

Another way that avoids the unsafe `eval`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

line="cpu=00:00:00,energy=0,fs/disk=1389.75K,mem=556K,pages=0,vmem=203640K"

# Turn the / into an underscore since / can't be in an identifier
# Then read the line into an array splitting on commas
IFS=, read -ra vars <<<"${line//\//_}"
# Define all the variables
declare -- "${vars[@]}"
# And display them
declare -p cpu energy fs_disk mem pages vmem
```

prints out

```bash
declare -- cpu="00:00:00"
declare -- energy="0"
declare -- fs_disk="1389.75K"
declare -- mem="556K"
declare -- pages="0"
declare -- vmem="203640K"
```

Comment: As long as names are valid bash variable identifiers, this is ok. Otherwise it is safer to populate an associative array if using bash version 4.2 or above.

Comment: @LéaGris agreed

Answer (score 1):

If using bash version at laest 4.0, it is safer to parse it into an associative array that can store arbitrary key strings. Otherwise, some identifiers will fail dramatically as invalid Bash variable identifiers like `fs/disk` which cannot be used as a Bash variable name:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

line='cpu=00:00:00,energy=0,fs/disk=1389.75K,mem=556K,pages=0,vmem=203640K'

# Read the line into a regular array, splitting keys and values at , and = signs
IFS=,= read -r -a kv <<<"$line"

# Generates an Associative array elements delcarations
# by print quoting [key]=value pairs
# shellcheck disable=SC2155 # Safely generated declaration
declare -A map="($(
  printf '[%q]=%q ' "${kv[@]}"
))"

# Print out a nice output for demo purpose:
for k in "${!map[@]}"; do
  printf '%-8s %s\n' "$k" "${map[$k]}"
done
```

Output:

```
fs/disk  1389.75K
vmem     203640K
cpu      00:00:00
pages    0
energy   0
mem      556K
```

Alternate method to populate the Associative array from the line, using a loop:

```bash
declare -A map=()
while IFS='=' read -r -d, k v; do
  map["$k"]="$v"
done <<<"$line"
```

Comment: @pjh fixed mention of minimum Bash version

Answer (score -1):

try

```
eval `echo 'cpu=00:00:00,energy=0,fs/disk=1389.75K,mem=556K,pages=0,vmem=203640K' | tr ',/' ';_'`
```

Comment: Nice. `eval` did the trick.

Comment: All bad and dangerous practice. `eval` can lead to unwanted execution of statement contained into string. Back-tick are deprecated constructs since like 25 years ago.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that, as long as you have complete control over the input and it's something you trust.

Comment: Your concern about that is only when there is a possibility of malicious input.